# Error with playing sounds

Tags: java, audio

I have faced an error with playing sounds on button click in java. I have a field of buttons and if any button is pressed application plays a sound. But application throws me an exception:

```
  javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: unable to obtain a line
```

Method look like this and is called when button was pressed:

```
public void playSound() {
    try {
        File file = new File("Sounds/sound.wav");
        AudioInputStream hitStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = hitStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(hitStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sound play at the beginning then it crashes. I googled the exception, found that the clip should be closed after playing sound. I thought I should add lines after **clip.start()**

```
if (!clip.isRunning()) {
   clip.stop();
   clip.close();        
}
```

But then the sounds don't play and whole application start to lag. What is the correct solution for this error?

Comment: On which line is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Are you sure the `wav` file is found and read?